# Inserting a new entry to android calendar

Tags: java, android, calendar, android-intent, vcalendar

I am trying to add a new event into the android calendar. Here is the code I am using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
                    intent.putExtra("title", event.getSummary());
                    intent.putExtra("description", event.getDescription());
                    intent.putExtra("eventLocation", event.getLocation());
                    intent.putExtra("dtstart", event.getStartDate());
                    if(event.getEndDate() == null)
                    {
                        intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        intent.putExtra("dtend", event.getEndDate());
                    }

                    startActivity(intent);
```

I am implementing this method in a separate class which is not an activity class. So I am extending the activity class here.

When i execute last line startActivity(intent); I am getting java nullpointer exception.

No idea how to proceed.

How could I add a entry in to android calendar?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you instantiating your activity class with `new`? You can not do that. Activity classes must be instantiated by OS in order to be functional.

Solution:

You have to have a reference to `Context` in order to call `context.startActivity(..)`. Pass an instance of context to your class in constructor. Hint: all Activities are Contexts, so just do `new MyClass(this)` from within an Activity.

Also, your class does not need to extend Activity.